# OAuth consent screen not showing for Google

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to access google drive through OAuth for local development.
I've included the
[following scopes:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KH6I.png)

The last scope being: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

However, when I get the client id, and use it in my local app, I am only asked to sign it through google. I'm not asked for any permission regarding the drive file access.
I further check it by reading the access token which I obtain after logging in. Among its details in json format, the scopes show the following:

"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid",

I'm not sure why I'm not getting the scope of drive.file in this. I've not submitted the app for verification (it's just a test app hosted locally after all). What am I missing?

Comment: I assume you first tried the app without adding `drive.file`? If that's the case, maybe you didn't delete the token file that was created first time, and so the application is reusing this one. Can you check if that's the case? If it's not the case, could provide the relevant parts of the code you're working on?

Comment: That was indeed the issue! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on iOS because I was using [React Native Google Signin](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin) and I needed to explicitly call [`addScopes()`](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin#addscopesoptions--scopes-arraystring-) after signing in. Read [why this is required](https://github.com/google/GoogleSignIn-iOS/issues/23).